# Can I add minicart functionality to a custom block (thats a modal), using RWD child theme? Magento 1.9.2.4

Tags: magento-1.9, product, checkout

I have added a custom block in my header and inside it is a button called Get a Quote. I've integrated Foundation into my RWD child theme, so when hovered over, a modal appears.

What I'd like to happen, is that the modal will act almost like the minicart. So when the customer adds a product it goes into the "minicart/modal" and shows just the image, qty, price per product. 
Plus the subtotal(quote amount) and go to checkout/clear buttons of the standard minicart.

So far I can add the product details, but I'm sure Im doing it wrong.

`<?php $session = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session'); $items = $session->getQuote()->getAllItems(); ?>`

`<?php if(count($items)): ?>`

`<?php foreach($items as $_item): ?>`

`<?php $isVisibleProduct = $_item->getProduct()->isVisibleInSiteVisibility();?>`

`<?php $product = $_item->getProduct(); ?>`

`<div class="row">`

`<div class="large-3 columns">`

`<a href="<?php echo $product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" class="product-image"><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'small_image')->resize(50, 50); ?>" width="50" height="50" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" /></a>`

`</div>`

`<div class="large-3 columns">`
`<?php echo $_item->getName();?>`
`</div>`

`<div class="large-3 columns">`
`<?php echo $_item->getQty();?>`
`</div>`

`<div class="large-3 columns">`
`<?php echo $_item->getPrice();?>`
`</div>`

`</div>`

`<?php endforeach; ?>`

This will add the product details to the modal, but I can remove it or get a subtotal for all products.